# Java script IIF in a confirm script

Tags: java, javascript, vb.net

On my server-side page I have a piece of legacy script that I want to modify to test if a field is blank before I open the confirm window. This is what I tried, adding the $(#hdfldRecId) because If this field is blank, I don't want the confirm to open.

```
    scriptBlock = "function beforeDelete()" & vbCrLf & _
                      "{return($('#hdfldRecId').val() !> '' && confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?'));}"
If (Not ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("deletePromptScript")) Then
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), _
                                                   "deletePromptScript", _
                                                   scriptBlock, _
                                                   True)
End If

    'use the OnClientClick property of the button to cause the above
    'script to be executed when the button is clicked

btndelete.OnClientClick = "return(beforeDelete());"
```

When I execute the page, the debug indicates that () are missing but the pairings all match.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function beforeDelete()
{return($('#hdfldRecId').val() !> '' && confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?'));}//]]>
</script>
```

So I am not sure how I add this test to see if there is a value in the $(hdfldRecId) and if there is then execute the confirm dialog.

Thank you

Comment: return is not a method so get rid of the ( and ).  `"return beforeDelete();"`

Comment: I saw some "_" lost after  "vbCrLf &" What is this?

Comment: @patricK That's a VB convention, indicating the code continues on the next line (as VB's end of expression terminator is a newline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return is not a method so get rid of the ( and ).

```
"return beforeDelete();"
```

and not sure what !> is supposed to be. Guessing you want to check the length

```
function beforeDelete() { 
    return $('#hdfldRecId').val().length && confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
btndelete.OnClientClick = "beforeDelete;"
```

Or indeed:

```
btndelete.OnClientClick = "return beforeDelete();"
```

As well as fixing the typo that epascarello pointed out.